# python count number of times the date has appeared

Tags: python

From the following array,how to count the dates for the number of times it has occured in the array.The output should be in the following format [date,count]

```
   new_dates =  [['2012-12-02', 14],['2012-12-03',2],....]
```

Input:

```
  dates = [['2012-12-02', 17], ['2012-12-01', 5], ['2012-12-02', 15], ['2012-12-02', 8], ['2012-12-02', 17], ['2012-12-02', 15], ['2012-12-11', 6], ['2012-12-02', 1], ['2012-12-02', 9], ['2012-12-02', 11], ['2012-12-03', 13], ['2012-12-03', 10], ['2012-12-02', 18], ['2012-12-02', 11], ['2012-12-02', 12], ['2012-12-05', 14], ['2012-12-02', 3], ['2012-12-02', 6], ['2012-12-06', 10], ['2012-12-07', 0], ['2012-12-08', 3], ['2012-12-09', 12], ['2012-12-02', 6]]
```

Comment: I didn't understand difference between input and output

Comment: i want to count the number of times a date has occured..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [[k,c[k]] for k in Counter([i[0] for i in dates])]
[['2012-12-01', 1], ['2012-12-02', 14], ['2012-12-03', 2], ['2012-12-05', 1], ['
2012-12-06', 1], ['2012-12-07', 1], ['2012-12-08', 1], ['2012-12-09', 1], ['2012
-12-11', 1]]
```

In case you can't use counter, use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in dates:
...    d[i[0]] += 1
...
>>> [[k,d[k]] for k in d]
[['2012-12-01', 1], ['2012-12-02', 14], ['2012-12-03', 2], ['2012-12-05', 1], ['
2012-12-06', 1], ['2012-12-07', 1], ['2012-12-08', 1], ['2012-12-09', 1], ['2012
-12-11', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, if can't use Counter, I suggest a loop/count solution:

by using Dict.get(a) ,will return None if there isn't a key in Dict, and will return value if there is a key "a" in dict

```
>>> dates = [['2012-12-02', 17], ['2012-12-01', 5], ['2012-12-02', 15], ['2012-12-02', 8], ['2012-12-02', 17], ['2012-12-02', 15], ['2012-12-11', 6], ['2012-12-02', 1], ['2012-12-02', 9], ['2012-12-02', 11], ['2012-12-03', 13], ['2012-12-03', 10], ['2012-12-02', 18], ['2012-12-02', 11], ['2012-12-02', 12], ['2012-12-05', 14], ['2012-12-02', 3], ['2012-12-02', 6], ['2012-12-06', 10], ['2012-12-07', 0], ['2012-12-08', 3], ['2012-12-09', 12], ['2012-12-02', 6]]
>>> dict_ = {}
>>> for i,j in dates:
     if dict_.get(i):
         dict_[i] += 1
     else:
         dict_[i] = 1

>>> dict_
{'2012-12-01': 1, '2012-12-02': 14, '2012-12-03': 2, '2012-12-05': 1, '2012-12-06': 1, '2012-12-07': 1, '2012-12-08': 1, '2012-12-09': 1, '2012-12-11': 1}
```

Comment: By the way, this is longhand way of what `defaultdict(int)` does. Since you don't use `j`, you can use `i` and then subscript it in your loop.